# iCloud Backup for .sqlite database file for CoreData in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I am currently working on an iOS project where I'm using Core Data for local data storage. Now, I'd like to upload my .sqlite database file to iCloud for synchronization and backup purposes. Can someone guide me on the steps and best practices for accomplishing this task?

- How can I configure my Core Data stack to work with iCloud?
- What are the steps to upload my .sqlite database file to iCloud Drive programmatically?
- Are there any considerations or potential issues to be aware of when dealing with iCloud and Core Data integration?

I am attaching my backup file code-block here.

```
class BackUp : NSObject {
    
    var query: NSMetadataQuery!
      
        let iCloudContainerIdentifier = "-----------"
        private let databaseName = "projectName.sqlite"
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "projectName")
    
      override init() {
          super.init()
          initialiseQuery()
          addNotificationObservers()
       }
    
    
    func initialiseQuery() {
           
           query = NSMetadataQuery.init()
           query.operationQueue = .main
           query.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope]
           query.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, databaseName)
       }
    
    
        private func retrieveLocalURL() -> URL {
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let documentaryDirectory = urls[0]
            let realmURL = documentaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Yoodoo.sqlite");
    
            return realmURL
        }
    
    func startBackup() throws {
            let fileURL =  retrieveLocalURL()//Bundle.main.url(forResource: "projectName", withExtension: "sqlite") else { return }
        
        if let containerURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: iCloudContainerIdentifier) {
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: containerURL.path) {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: containerURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
            let backupFileURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent(databaseName)
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: backupFileURL.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: backupFileURL)
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileURL, to: backupFileURL)
            } else {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileURL, to: backupFileURL)
            }
            
            query.operationQueue?.addOperation({ [weak self] in
                _ = self?.query.start()
                self?.query.enableUpdates()
            })
        } else{
            print("Container Not Found...!")
        }
        
//        guard let containerURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: iCloudContainerIdentifier) else { return }
            
           
        }
    
    
    func addNotificationObservers() {
                            
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidStartGathering, object: query, queue: query.operationQueue) { (notification) in
                self.processCloudFiles()
            }
            
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object: query, queue: query.operationQueue) { (notification) in
                self.processCloudFiles()
            }
        }
    
    
    @objc func processCloudFiles() {
            
            if query.results.count == 0 { return }
            var fileItem: NSMetadataItem?
            var fileURL: URL?
            
            for item in query.results {
                
                guard let item = item as? NSMetadataItem else { continue }
                guard let fileItemURL = item.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey) as? URL else { continue }
                if fileItemURL.lastPathComponent.contains(databaseName) {
                    fileItem = item
                    fileURL = fileItemURL
                }
            }
            
            let fileValues = try? fileURL!.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemIsUploadingKey])
            if let fileUploaded = fileItem?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey) as? Bool, fileUploaded == true, fileValues?.ubiquitousItemIsUploading == false {
                print("backup upload complete")

            } else if let error = fileValues?.ubiquitousItemUploadingError {
                print("upload error---", error.localizedDescription)
                
            } else {
                if let fileProgress = fileItem?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey) as? Double {
                    print("uploaded percent ---", fileProgress)
                }
            }
        }
    
    func restoreBackup() throws {
        guard let containerURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: iCloudContainerIdentifier) else {
            print("Container Not Found...!")
            return
        }

        let backupFileURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent(databaseName)

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: backupFileURL.path) {
            let localURL = retrieveLocalURL()

            do {
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localURL.path) {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: localURL)
                }
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: backupFileURL, to: localURL)
                print("Data restored successfully.")
            } catch {
                print("Failed to restore data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Backup file not found in iCloud.")
        }
    }
}
```

- I have enabled capabilities for iCloud in Xcode and also created Manual and Automatic both iCloud Containers for storing the data.
- Also I have tried different functions with different type of database object like privateDatabase and Public Database.

Expectation:

- I am expecting whole the .sqlite database file (with the all Tables) should be uploaded on the iCloud and whenever we install the app again and if there is a .sqlite database file on iCloud exist then it should replace with the local one.